# Using the Map Function in a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, return, map-function

I have a React component. It loads a local JSON file. In the constructor I want to loop through the local JSON file, find an item that matches a URL parameter, and set some state values. Here is my code so far:

```js
import React,{Component} from "react";

import topics from './topics.json';

class Tutorial extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    topics.map((topic, index) => {

      if(topic.url === this.props.match.params.url)
      {
        this.state = {
          url: this.props.match.params.url,
          name: topic.name
        };
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Tutorial">

        <div className="ca-nav-spacer w3-hide-small"></div>

          {this.state.name}
          {this.state.url}

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Tutorial;
```

I keep getting this error: **Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function**.

Must the map function return a value? If I'm not returning a value should I just use a for loop? Can I return the block of JSON and then set the state after the map? What would be the proper way to do this?

Edit: Changed page to topic

Comment: Yes, you would use `forEach` or something instead of `map`, but I don't think this use case should use either. A better way to do it would be to use a `find` array method to get the one matching `topic` and then just set the state once.

Comment: Can you also post the structure of your JSON

Comment: Unless you want to produce a new array, I don't recommend using map as your iterator. Also, What is the `page` variable here? I don't see it declared anywhere.

Comment: @DanZuzevich, You're right. May be `topic.page.url`

Answer (score 3):

My strong recommendation is two-fold:

- Use the `find` method to find the correct topic.
- Don't use state to redundantly store information you already have from props. Storing information you already have can result in *divergence*. In this case, we can just `find` the appropriate topic in the render method:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import topics from "./topics.json";

class Tutorial extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const selectedTopic = topics.find(
      (topic, index) => page.url === this.props.match.params.url
    );

    return (
      <div className="Tutorial">
        <div className="ca-nav-spacer w3-hide-small"></div>
        {selectedTopic.name}
        {this.props.match.params.url}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Tutorial;
```

Comment: This would work! +1 , but @Nick, is it more costly?

Comment: Where is the `page` variable coming from?

Comment: @smilyface I guess it's more expensive than doing it on mount but only because it's going to not be reactive to prop updates which would seem pretty bad!

Comment: @DanZuzevich I had that question too; my guess is OP left something out of the question.

Comment: I love when that happens.

Comment: @DanZuzevich in this case I can't think of a scenario in which the definition of `page` changes my answer

Comment: @smilyface I think it's also important to recognize that 99.999% of react apps will not have to worry about optimizations like caching `find` calls. Sure, it can be done, but I would much rather have a render variable than redundant state and only cross the optimization bridge if truly necessary.

Comment: If props very rarely change, and if any new state is added that rarely changes as well, I'd say this is a good solution. Too bad this wasn't using hooks, so you could wrap the find function with a useMemo. Ill upvote this.

Answer (score 0):

Although find would work in most situations, it won't for reasons I did not include. I ended up using a forEach loop in the constructor.

```js
constructor(props){
  super(props);

  topics.forEach((topic) => {

    if(topic.url === this.props.match.params.url)
    {
      this.state = {
        url: topic.url,
        title: topic.title
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing your JSON structure, it's hard to answer

---

Changing {} to () might work

from `map(() => {})` to `map(() => ())`

Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function array-callback-return react

---

### Another answer

Try using `forEach` (replace `map` with `forEach`) I guess your JSON does not returns an array.

Comment: The actual JSON I'm using is a list of topics with articles inside the topics. I didn't post it because once I had the best way to iterate through my JSON I figured I could take it from there.